# Read a variable from a JSON file

Tags: php, json

Good evening,

I am retrieving a JSON file and trying to read a variable at the very end of the file.

```
$eedomus_api_user = 'xyz';
$eedomus_api_secret = 'zzz';
$periph_id = 'yyy';

$url = "http://19X.XXX.0.XX/api/get?";
$url .= "api_user=$eedomus_api_user";
$url .= "&api_secret=$eedomus_api_secret";
$url .= "&action=periph.value";
$url .= "&periph_id=$periph_id";

$result = file_get_contents($url);

$phpObj =  json_decode($result, true);
```

The file I'm getting is the following :

```
{ "success": 1, "body":{"last_value": 100} }
```

I'm interested in getting the '100' corresponding to the last_value field.

Using the function strpos, I'm intending to look for the position of the first '}' and retrieve the characters until the previous space. Is there an easier way to achieve this ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your `$phpObj` contains the decoded array already, `$phpObj['body']['last_value']` should give `100`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @kerbh0lz: Thank you very much. It is indeed a lot easier :-) Have a good evening